# H2 performance for large objects

Tags: h2

In our benchmarking we found that H2 does not perform well for large objects. Is there any size limit for the objects which we store in H2?

Comment: You need to provide more info. What exactly did you try?

Answer (score 1):

As long as you use the data types CLOB / BLOB (or the aliases), then there is no size limit.

But as for performance problems, you would need to provide more info about what you did.